# How to manage a SVN project that is spread across multiple folders?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Here is what my svn repository look like:

```
/
/libraries
  /libA
  /libB
  /libC
/tools
/projects
  /proj1
  /proj2
/website
```

I am making changes in libA and proj1.  I want to set it up so that I can submit my changes in libA and proj1 together. The challenge in not to check out the entire repository.  I would prefer the solution to be Tortoise SVN friendly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use sparse checkouts in Subversion 1.5.

Read more about it here: [Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

This will allow you to checkout the root repository directory to a local directory, but not everything beneath it.

Answer (score 2):

I've heard a few different ways to do this, but my preferred method is via [SVN Externals](http://claudio.cicali.org/article/71/svnexternals-micro-howto).

Comment: I can't use externals, because other people are working on the whole set of libraries.  I don't want to make them get my project.

Comment: That's backwards.  Your project adds an externals property to pull the libraries in, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting into the realm where using a real IDE or plain command-line may be more powerful than any GUI.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ has terrific integration with SVN built-in.  I use that.

Tortoise SVN is a Windows Explorer interface for SVN.  But I barely use it because IntelliJ is so good.